# Appcelerator Titanium studio unable to create new project - Missing required option ''--username''

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I'm using Titanium for the first time and have just installed it. I'm trying to create a new project, but every time I receive the following:

```
Unable to create new project [ERROR] Missing required option ''--username''
```

I'm running Windows XP. I have the JRE bin in my path.

So far, I've done the following:

• uninstalled and reinstalled so it wasn't under the "Program Files" folder

• Confirmed the JRE 7 bin and Android SDK paths to my machine's path

• created the JAVA_HOME and pointed it to my Java root folder

• confirmed that there are no "Titanium Updates" required.

The workspace logs indicate:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2013-11-01 10:04:31.239 !MESSAGE System property https.proxyHost is not set but should be <MyProxyServerAddress>.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2013-11-01 10:04:31.239 !MESSAGE System property https.proxyPort is not set but should be <MyProxyServerPort>.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2013-11-01 10:04:58.818 !MESSAGE NLS missing message: BasicProjectCreationPage_crossPlatformWarningAndroid in: com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.wizard.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2013-11-01 10:04:58.818 !MESSAGE NLS missing message: BasicProjectCreationPage_crossPlatformWarningIOS in: com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.wizard.messages

!ENTRY com.appcelerator.titanium.acs.ui 4 0 2013-11-01 10:05:21.256 !MESSAGE (Build 3.1.3.201309132423) [ERROR] Failed to log into Node.ACS: [ERROR] Login failed. Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Not experienced this myself.. I would try logging in and out of Titanium Studio.. Searching for a way to clear the login credentials, failing that re-install TiStudio. You might have better look in the Appcelerator developer q & a